# Trying to get a div to always match the height of a div whose height is constantly increasing and decreasing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that contains a list of items. The user is able to add to/remove items from the list, so the div constantly changes height to compensate for the changing size of the list.

I have another div to its right that is supposed to give details about the items on the left. How can I get the div on the right to constantly keep vertically aligned with the left div and change height so that it equals the height that the left div currently is, as items are added and removed from the left div's list?

I tried to implement tables for this solution, but I find that it isn't working with my code, so instead I tried this JS code...

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r6sc27ck/

The code might achieve what I want but the background on the left div isn't displaying so something's going wrong...

HTML

```
<div id="Div2">Hello2</div>
<br>
<div id="Div1">Hello1</div>
```

CSS

```
#Div1{
    background-color:blue;
}

#Div2{
    background-color:red;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    document.onchange=setDivHeight();

function setDivHeight(){
    var x=Number(document.getElementById('Div1').style.height)
    document.getElementById('Div2').style.height=x;
}

});



setInterval(function() {
   $('#Div1').eq(0).append('<p>appended content</p>')
}, 1000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r6sc27ck/

Comment: Why not just put the details in the same div?

Comment: I don't see left / right div. I see a upper / lower div?

Comment: Sorry. Try http://jsfiddle.net/r6sc27ck/
This actually might be working but I can't even tell if it is because the background color for the left div isn't displaying...

Comment: I can't put the details in the same div because at some point I need the details to be set to display:none, but I still want the other info to always be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using document.onchange, you should call setDivHeight() in the end of the process that add content to the div.
I also modified the style and the content of setDivHeight().

http://jsfiddle.net/r6sc27ck/4/

```
var prevHeight;
$(document).ready(function(){    
      prevHeight = $('#Div1').height();
});
function setDivHeight(){
    var curHeight = $('#Div1').height();            
    if (prevHeight !== curHeight) {
        prevHeight = curHeight;
        setDivHeight();
    }            
    $('#Div2').height($('#Div1').height());  

}


setInterval(function() {
   $('#Div1').eq(0).append('<p>appended content</p>');
    setDivHeight();
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. The other answers were helping a lot, but yours was directly on point and is actually working even better than expected on my page. I will be keeping this code. Thank you for providing this wonderful solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 divs next to eachother you can allign them by setting vertical-allign:

```
div{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnt83hz7/2/)

Comment: Thanks. I implemented that in the fiddle now.

This might be almost working, but the background color is disappearing for the left div. Any ideas on how to fix that problem? http://jsfiddle.net/r6sc27ck/ Also, if I change the code to append Div2 instead of Div1, the text doesn't stay inside Div2. =/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the two divs to `display:table-cell` and the containing div to `display:table`. Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r6sc27ck/1/

Also there are many ways to achieve this, have a look here. https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 1):

Try

css

```
#Div1 {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:blue;
    width:35%;
}
#Div2 {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    width:35%;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#Div1").eq(0).append("<p>appended content</p>");
        $("#Div2").eq(0).append("<p>&nbsp;</p>");
    }, 1000)
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vnt83hz7/4/

Comment: Oh, wow! That makes things a lot easier =) And that makes perfect sense. Thank you, I'm excited to use this solution on my webpage.